# Checkbox on Contact & Lead List View in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, contact

In the contact & lead list view checkboxes are coming in Lightning. Checkboxes are only coming on these two object's list view and not on other objects. Is there any setting for it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the checkboxes due to a feature released in Winter'17 See [this release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_sales_mass_actions_add_to_campaign.htm) note documentation.

> *From lead and contact list views*, reps can use the Add to Campaign button to effortlessly add up to 200 members at a time. As with Salesforce Classic, reps must assign a status to new members and can choose whether to also give the status to existing members.

Not sure if you can add it to other object, but this is cause of having checkboxes in contact and lead objects.

---

**Update**: Steps to have checkboxes in a list view. It is same as we do in classic UI.

1. Create List view button:
   [image]
2. Add to list view.
3. Result:
   [image]

Note: Its not visible in *Recently viewed* view.

Comment: I can see other objects are also having these check-boxes in list view , is there any reason to have these in list view, I can't find any operation available using checkbox except for the thing you mentioned above.